# How to Load Xml File in Business Central

Tags: xml, import, dynamics-business-central, xml-formatting, xml-import

I have a below code in NaV 13 and i want to write same logic in business central on SAAS.

Xmldoc:= xmldoc.xmldocument;
xmldoc.load(FileName);

Xmldoc is dot net variable in navision. How can i write same login in business central on saas as dot net variables are not available on saas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upload the file content to an `InStream`.

You can do this with the `UploadIntoStream` procedure:

```
UploadIntoStream('*.xml', XmlInStream);
```

`XmlInStream` is a variable of type `InStream`.

Next you need to use the new XML data types to load the XML Document from the stream:

```
XmlDocument.ReadFrom(XmlInStream, MyXmlDocument);
```

`MyXmlDocument` is a variable of type `XmlDocument`.

You can then start processing the XML Document through the `MyXmlDocument` variable and the use of the XML data types.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know specifically how you are using it this might not answer your question directly, but it should point you in the right direction.

This is one way to upload an XML file to a variable in Business Central.
More information on the XmlDocument Data Type can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/xmldocument/xmldocument-data-type)

```
local procedure XMLImportFunction()
var
    Ins: InStream;
    FileName: Text;
    XmlDoc: XmlDocument;
    Root: XmlElement;
begin
    if UploadIntoStream('Import File', '', '', FileName, InS) then begin
        if XmlDocument.ReadFrom(InS, XmlDoc) then begin
            XmlDoc.GetRoot(Root);
        end;
    end;
end;
```